# Firebase Storage: Still get 404 Error despite handling it

Tags: javascript, firebase, error-handling, http-status-code-404, firebase-storage

- In an HR webapp I have a list of candidates that are rendered to the
  DOM.
- Each one does either have a CV in Firebase Storage or not. Thus I need to determine which button I should display: 'Download CV' or 'Upload CV'.
- To check this, I am calling .getDowloadURL() on the file ref.
- If a CV is found, the 'Download CV' button is displayed, and everything is fine
- If nothing is found, an error is returned
- I then catch this error and handle it to display the "Upload CV" button on the DOM

My problem is that I still get 404 errors in the console for each candidate that does not have a CV. (I have also tried with onResolve, onReject, but the problem is the same).

I am very thankful for any hint!

This is my code:

```
    firebase.storage().ref().child('cvs').child(doc.id).child('CV').getDownloadURL()
        .then(function (url) {
            
            document.getElementById('dwlCvBtn' + doc.id).classList.remove('d-none')


        }).catch(function (error) {


            // A full list of error codes is available at
            // https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors
            switch (error.code) {
                case 'storage/object-not-found':
                    document.getElementById('uploadCvBtn' + doc.id).classList.remove('d-none')
                    break;

                case 'storage/unauthorized':
                    // User doesn't have permission to access the object
                    break;

                case 'storage/canceled':
                    // User canceled the upload
                    break;

                case 'storage/unknown':
                    // Unknown error occurred, inspect the server response
                    break;
            }
            
        });
```

Comment: I know this is an old question, but: Did you find any solution? I am facing the exact same problem. Not a big issue, but it bugs me somehow...

Comment: No I still get those errors. Everything works but on a very large list it also bugs me to have 100+ errors in the console...

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you're looking for but:

The error is caught in the catch - it will produce a `storage/object-not-found` error code.

The error you're seeing might be a Chrome browser feature.

Source: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6969#issuecomment-1399923859